# How to set cron to run a file accurately in seconds?

Tags: cron

I want set run a file with cron at `12:03:37` every day. How do I set set cron to run a file accurately in seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set it up to run at 12:03 and then sleep for 37 seconds:

```
3 12 * * * root sleep 37; /path/to/your/script
```